# SKNode Subclass Not Moving Children

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a sprite that can't exist in my game without a pairing `SKFieldNode` so my solution was to create a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and create a property for the `SKFieldNode` but it didn't work because the `SKSpriteNode` was acting weird (I don't remember exactly what happened). So my next approach was to change the subclass to `SKNode` and then I would make the `SKSpriteNode` and the `SKFieldNode` a property of this new `SKNode`. But then it turns out that `touchesMoved` will only move one of the properties (whichever is on top) which turns out to always be the `SKSpriteNode`.

What's the best approach to this problem, and how can I fix it so that I can have an `SKFieldNode` for every `SKSpriteNode` while still making sure that actions and methods still work properly.

Current code of `SKNode` subclass:

```
@interface Whirlpool : SKNode
- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)pos region:(float)region strength:(float)strength falloff:(float)falloff;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKFieldNode *gravityField;
@end

#import "Whirlpool.h"
#import "Categories.h"

@implementation Whirlpool
- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)pos region:(float)region strength:(float)strength falloff:(float)falloff {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // whirlpool sprite
        SKSpriteNode *whirlpoolSprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"whirlpool"];
        whirlpoolSprite.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        whirlpoolSprite.position = pos;
        //removing physicsBody and associated attributes for now so that the boat does not collide with the whirlpool
        //whirlpoolSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:whirlpoolSprite.size.width / 2];
        //whirlpoolSprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        whirlpoolSprite.zPosition = 1;
        whirlpoolSprite.name = @"whirlpool";
        [whirlpoolSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[self sharedRotateAction]]];

        // whirlpool gravity field
        _gravityField = [SKFieldNode radialGravityField];
        _gravityField.position = pos;
        _gravityField.strength = strength;
        _gravityField.falloff = falloff;
        _gravityField.region = [[SKRegion alloc] initWithRadius:region];
        _gravityField.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = gravityFieldCategory;
        _gravityField.zPosition = 1;

        [self addChild:whirlpoolSprite];
        [self addChild:_gravityField];
    }

    return self;
}

- (SKAction *)sharedRotateAction {
    static SKAction *rotateWhirlpool;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        rotateWhirlpool = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI * 2 duration:4.0];
    });

    return rotateWhirlpool;
}

@end
```

---

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // we don't want the player to be able to move the whirlpools after the button is pressed
    if (_isRunning) {
        return;
    }

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        // if the finger touches the boat or the whirlpool, update its location
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"boat"]) {
            node.position = CGPointMake(location.x, node.position.y);
        } else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"whirlpool"]) {
            node.position = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `touchesMoved` as well?

Comment: @ChrisSlowik Updated the post with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issues comes down to that fact that "whirlpool" is a child of your SKNode subclass. So when you are identifying that you are indeed touching a "whirlpool" you are moving it within its parent (the SKNode subclass) and the SKFieldNode and parent stay put. This little adjustment to your original code should work...if I understand the problem correctly.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // we don't want the player to be able to move the whirlpools after the button is pressed
    if (_isRunning) {
        return;
    }

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        // if the finger touches the boat or the whirlpool, update its location
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"boat"]) {
            node.position = CGPointMake(location.x, node.position.y);
        } else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"whirlpool"]) {
            //move the SKNode subclass the whirlpool is a child of
            node.parent.position = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, the problem here is the way you are grabbing nodes, you may be grabbing the wrong nodes due to all the children.  Instead take this approach:

We already know that you are subclassing your sprites, so in your subclasses, add the following code:

```
//Whirlpool 
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];//Unless you are retaining the scene in the child, then use that
        self.position = location;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
//Boat 
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];//Unless you are retaining the scene in the child, then use that
        self.position.x = location.x;
    }
}
```

Then for your Scene, do this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // we don't want the player to be able to move the whirlpools after the button is pressed
    if (_isRunning) {
        return;
    }
    //At this point it should call the children on touch events
    [super.touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event];
}
```